# $g : Z \rightarrow W$ a regular covering map where $Z$ and $W$ are path-connected, and $\pi_1(Z)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose that $g : Z \rightarrow W$ is a regular covering map where $Z$ and $W$ are path-connected, and $\pi_1(Z) = Z_2.$ Is it true that $g_* : H_1(Z) \rightarrow H_1(W )$ is injective?  Prove or give a counterexample. $\phantom{}$

This is not a homework question, but rather a question for self study.  Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

This is true! The point is that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and $H$ has $2$ elements, then it is in the center of $G$. Hence the inclusion $H\to G$ induces an injection on the abelianization: $H\to G/[G,G]$. In particular, if $Z\to W$ is a covering map as in your question, we have $\pi_1(Z)$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(W)$, and since $H_1$ is just the abelianization of $\pi_1$, the statement follows.